# Merge values from two mutually exclusive DataSets' into a separate DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

What are the possible methods to merge values from two mutually exclusive DataSets' into a separate DataSet?

Comment: More information please.  Are you talking about ADO.NET datasets or some other type of data structure?

Comment: I meant ADO.Net datasets only!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DataSet a = // Some Pre-filled DataSet.
DataSet b = // Some Other Pre-filled DataSet.

DataSet c = a.Copy();
c.Merge(b);
```